# Shift bin edges in uniform bin size - Python

Tags: python, histogram, binning, discretization

I want to bin my data using fixed bin size but want to be able to shift bin edges to manipulate the number of data that ends up in bins. My only constraint is bin size and i want to maximize data points in successive bins

eg:

```
data = [10, 10, 10, 10, 13, 15, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
binsize = 2
B = int((data.max() - data.min())/binsize) #Calculate bin width

pd.cut(data, B)
```

The above code would create 4 bins, 9.99 to 11.6, 11.6 to 13.2 and so on which would result in 4 data points in first bin, 1 data point in second bin, 3 in third bin.

(i do not need this for a histogram, but added the tag as it covers the same concept)

is there anyway short of writing a function using for loops to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

Feel like an idiot, i can just make custom edges of uniform width instead of giving a fixed number of bins